# Cómo poner un límite de tamaño a las imágenes subidas con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente archivo upload.php con el cual subo imágenes. El archivo es de un script, y este no viene con comprobación de tamaño desde el lado del servidor.

```
$targetFolder = 'uploads/'; // Relative to the root


if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $response = array ();
    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        $response['success'] = 1;
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $response[$key] = $value;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['error'] = 'Invalid file type.';
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Me gustaría ponerle un límite de 1MB. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de tres maneras:
La primera es limitar el tamaño de los envíos en `php.ini`. Hay dos directivas en las que debes fijar el valor `1M` para limitar a un mega: `upload_max_filesize` y `post_max_size`. La última limita el peso de todo el envío, ficheros y textos, todo incluido. Sin embargo, como los textos no suelen tener gran peso, a efectos prácticos te está limitando el peso del fichero.
Esto tiene varios problemas. En primer lugar, no siempre puedes acceder al fichero de configuración. Si tienes tu web en un hosting compartido no puedes, y el proveedor no te va a cambiar eso.
Además, el problema es que el fichero, si pesa más, no es recibido por tu script php, pero no te muestra, por defecto, un fallo. Es decir. El usuario podría creer que su fichero ha subido. La solución es usar la propiedad `error` de los ficheros enviados. Si tu campo de fichero se llama, digamos, `mi_imagen`, puedes poner un filtro en el PHP que busque el valor de `$_FILES["mi_imagen"]["error"]`. Si todo ha ido bien, este valor es `0`. Si se ha pasado el límite, el valor es un número distinto de `0`.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es mirar la propiedad `size` del fichero enviado. Está en `$_FILES["mi_imagen"]["size"]`. Si supera `1048576` el fichero pesa más de un mega. Puedes mostrarle al usuario un mensaje de error, en ese caso.

El problema es que estas opciones funcionan con PHP en el lado del servidor... una vez se ha hecho el envío. Tienes que mostrarle al usuario su error y devolverle de nuevo al formulario. Es decir, ya estás introduciendo pasos de programación para un archivo que no sabrás si es correcto o no, hasta que estés en el servidor.

La solución es comprobarlo, con jQuery, en el propio formulario, *ANTES* de hacer el envío. Por ejemplo, así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formulario" action="destino.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="mi_imagen" id="mi_imagen">
        <input type="button" value="comprobar" id="boton_comprobar">
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
        $("#boton_comprobar").on('click', function(){
            var fichero = $('#mi_imagen')[0].files[0];
            var peso = fichero.size;
            console.log(peso);
            if (peso > 1048576) {
                alert ("El fichero es muy grande");
            } else {
                $("#formulario").submit();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este código es sólo un ejemplo, pero te permite comprobar el peso del archivo en el propio formulario. En el condicional puedes poner un alert, o lo que sea. Si el fichero está en un formulario, si pasa el control puedes enviar el formulario, como ves en el código. De este modo, si el campo no cumple, evitas un envío innecesario.

El código que te he puesto está comprobado y funcionando. Si quieres puedes añadirle una línea como la siguiente:

```
console.log(fichero);
```

De este modo verás que hay otras propiedades que puedes verificar antes del envío, como `type` (el tipo de fichero).

Es una solución bastante más limpia, en mi opinión.

Comment: Javascript no es un método fiable para poder controlar el tamaño de los archivos subidos al servidor ya que es altamente hackeable.

Comment: @FernandoUrban si método de JS se debe combinar con el de PHP, tal y como ha explicado, y de esta forma el usuario sabe si su archivo es válido antes de enviar la solicitud.

Comment: Mucgas gracias, lo de ["size"] me ha servido. La parte de jQuery ya la tiene implementada el script, pero será útil para los demás.

Comment: Como muy bien apunta Fernando Urban, cualquier código en JavaScript adolece de cierta vulnerabilidad inherente. Si tu página requiere medidas especiales de seguridad, porque el contenido vaya a ser sensible, te sugiero que consideres usar un framework como Angular, que, al pasar a producción, hace el JS menos legible para un posible intruso. Aún así, siempre habrá cierto riesgo, pero será mucho menor.